# What data is available on hospitalization rates of COVID-19 patients by risk factor?

Tags: epidemiology, covid-19, hospital

What data and analysis is available on hospitalization rates of COVID-19 patients by age and pre-existing condition?

Estimates of death rates have been communicated, but I have found no similar figures for hospitalization rates.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Here is best report I was able to find:
https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/who-china-joint-mission-on-covid-19-final-report.pdf

Comment: Somehow the test positive and mortality data are known and updated, but there is a complete lack of US hospitalization data. If test positive and mortality data are applied to many US encatchment areas as of 3/18/20 the most hospitals would have zero inpatient cases.

Comment: From https://www.businessinsider.com/us-coronavirus-hospitalizations-underlying-health-conditions-cdc-2020-3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFWtj.pnga